# Writing in the file

Tags: android, file, user-input

I am making an app which creates a floder. In that folder it I am creating a file and writing Radha in it. but it shows Hello World, CreateActivity the code is

Create.java

```
public class CreateActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //Context ctx = getApplicationContext(); 

    try { 
        File myDir = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()); 
        String s = ""; 

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(myDir + "/Test.txt"); 
        fw.write("Radha"); 
        fw.close(); 

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myDir + "/Test.txt")); 
        s = br.readLine(); 

        // Set TextView text here using tv.setText(s); 

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I want it to show Radha but its showing Hello World, CreateActivity

Answer (score 0):

What you write into the file has nothing to do with what's on the screen. Check the layout xml (res/layout/main.xml). (You are using this when you call `setContentView(R.layout.main);`.) The layout probably references a string resource that can be found in res/values/strings.xml. Change that string to change what's displayed on the screen.

I suggest that you go through the [Hello World tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) for Android to gain an understanding of these fundamentals.

Comment: ohk.. but with this code has the folder been created and Radha has been written on it..? aand how do i see the foler on the emulator..?

Comment: @RadhaKumar I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. You can use the `adb` command line tool to open a shell to the emulator. (Just run `adb shell` at the command line, assuming that you have the platform tools on your path.) Then you can poke around to find the file and `cat` its contents. Or are you perhaps trying to display the file contents on the screen? Perhaps you can clarify your question.

Comment: @RadhaKumar Once you have read the file contents into a String, just set that String as the text for the TextView in `main.xml`. If you haven't altered the default Hello World project, I believe that all you need is: `((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview)).setText(s);` at the end of your `onCreate` method. Note, however, that doing file I/O inside `onCreate` is not recommended, as explained [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/new-gingerbread-api-strictmode.html) and in many other places in the docs.